# Rounding a number while using string formatting in python

Tags: python, string, formatting, rounding

I'm wondering how to round a number in python while using string formatting. In my code, I used %r instead of %d, beacuse %d prints an interger. How do I round the numbers while using %r? I would like to have my numbers rounded to two decimal places.

```
def new_formula(value):
    payment = value * 9.00
    tips = payment/.29
    earned = payment + tips
    return payment, tips, earned

name = "Nate"
hours = 7.5

print "%s worked %r hours." % (name, hours)
print """He was paid %r dollars and made %r dollars in tips.
At the end of the day he earned %r dollars.""" % new_formula(hours)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you want to be using `%r` -- why not `%.2f` or `%0.2f`?

Comment: Also, python's built-in [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function may help.

Comment: I haven't seen those before. I'll give those a try.

Comment: If I were to use round(), would I just put the number to be rounded into the parenthesis and what it should be rounded to, like round(value, 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could always round the return statement. So, `round(payment, 2)` for example. And, I am not sure why you are using \r. (Could you tell me why?). You could do %.2f to use two decimal places instead.

Comment: I used %r because that is what i've been told to use in an online class I'm taking. I know that %s will pass a string into what I want to print, and that %d and %r will pass numbers. But I don't actually understand the differences.

Comment: I didn't know %r meant before your answer. It creates representation of an object that is good for debugging but not good for displaying to the user because it will display with ' characters around the result. In general, you would want to use %s for displaying strings, %d for displaying integers, and %f for passing real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function round:

```
print "%s worked %.2f hours." % (name, round(hours, 2))
```

The parameter 2 tells the function to use 2 digits after the decimal point.